# Rails - How do I change any key that has a string for a value in a hash into arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hash

I have the following form

```
<%  if (current_user.mod_of_game?(@guide) unless current_user.nil?) %>
   <%= form_for([@category, @page], url: update_pages_path) do |f| %>
   <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

     <%= select_tag 'content[key1]', options_for_select(['atk', 'def', 'hp', 'sing'], 'atk' ), { :multiple => true} %>


     <%= select_tag 'content[key2]', options_for_select(['atk', 'def', 'hp', 'sing'], 'atk' ), { :multiple => true} %>

     <%= select_tag 'content[key3]', options_for_select(['atk', 'def', 'hp', 'sing'], 'atk' ), { :multiple => true} %>

     <%= select_tag 'content[key4]', options_for_select(['atk', 'def', 'hp', 'sing'], 'atk' ), { :multiple => true} %>

     <%= f.submit "Save"  %>

  <% end %>
```

When the information is submitted it is stored into a params hash like so

```
content: {"key1"=>["atk", "def"], "key2"=>"hp", "key3"=>["hp", "sing"], "key4"=>"atk"}
```

The hash is then saved to the DB from the controller

```
 if @page.update (category_params)
   @page.update(table_content: params[:content])
   redirect_to show_pages_path(@category, @page)
   flash[:success] = "Updated."
 else
   render 'edit'
 end
```

I need all values in the hash to be arrays, even if it contains a single string. You can see key2 and key4 in the `content` has values that are strings.

I'm not sure if you can do this directly by changing the form setup but I've has no success trying it this way. My other alternative is changing the strings into hashes in the controller before it is saved to the DB.

With either case how can this be done? (I guess changing the hash values that are stings into arrays in the controller would be best considering the user cant change it from there).

Comment: Your `if (current_user.mod_of_game?(@guide) unless current_user.nil?)` construct looks strange even if it is valid. You might want to say `if current_user.try(:mod_of_game?, @guide)` instead, I think that would be more recognizable to other Rails devs that might look at your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace this line:

```
@page.update(table_content: params[:content])
```

with:

```
content = params[:content].each_with_object({}) do |(k, v), h|
  h[k] = v.is_a?(String) ? [v] : v
end
@page.update(table_content: content)
```

Answer (score 3):

If `arr` is an array, `[*arr] #=> arr`. If `obj` is a string or number, `[*obj] #=> [obj]`. Therefore:

```
h =  {"key1"=>["atk", "def"], "key2"=>"hp", "key3"=>["hp", "sing"], "key4"=>"atk"}

h.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),g| g[k] = [*h[k]] }
  #=> {"key1"=>["atk", "def"], "key2"=>["hp"], "key3"=>["hp", "sing"], "key4"=>["atk"]}
```

or

```
h.merge(h) { |_,v,_| [*v] }
  #=> {"key1"=>["atk", "def"], "key2"=>["hp"], "key3"=>["hp", "sing"], "key4"=>["atk"]}
```

Comment: Also works as an answer but @cmoran92 got in a little earlier.

Comment: user3234020, I have no problem with that, but why should an answer's timestamp have anything to do with selecting the answer that is the most helpful to you? See the [Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) about that. You'll see it makes no reference to timestamps. I can think of some mildly amusing situations in real life where the first-past-the-post-criteria does not always achieve the best result, but I will remain silent about that.

Comment: Haha well they both answer the question and I had to pick one so either I flip a coin or go for the first to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that we can not do this by changing the form setup. So we must change strings to hashes in controller.
Use before_action to change params like below.

```
before_action :changing_param_values

private
def changing_param_values
  params[:content].each do |key, value|
    params[:content][key] = [value] if value.is_a?(String)
  end
end
```